# BFGS convergence problem

Tags: optimization, convergence

I would like first to state that it is beyond my capability to identify whether this is a BFGS issue or a R package problem.

I've been doing some mixed logit regression using the R package "mlogit". In total I have 32 random parameters and one fixed parameter to be estimated. Correlations are allowed among random parameters. 
With BFGS method, the code stopped after 13 iteration. Judging from the Chi-square value, it is far from converge. With BHHH method, however, it usually converge (although very slowly). Is this a package problem? or is it BHHH method more appropriate than BFGS in my context?

I doubt if it is related to the step size, but it's only my doubt.
The code and data I've used are [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JIExSz5pq6iGgTWteW49quZ15Ptw_gCv).

Comment: welcome to scicomp! it's always best to include more information with your question(problem details, BFGS/BHHH convergence plots, chi-square values, etc.), instead of asking people to download and read through a data file...